# Detecting Which item was Selected From a ListView

Tags: android, listview, click, selected

I am trying to get the title of the song that was selected from my listview but I'm getting a forced close.  Any ideas?

```
    ArrayList<String>songtitle = new ArrayList<String>();

    //This is how i popluated sontitle//
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

 protected void onListIemClick(ListView  , View v, int position, long id){
       super.onListItemClick(c, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String pen = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the color: " + " " + songtitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: what is songtitle and selection?, post the code explaining those.

Comment: What is the songtitle variable?  The underlying list?  What is the exception causing the force close?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void onListIemClick(ListView  , View v, int position, long id){
     Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the color: " + songtitle.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

try this.

Comment: I have made the question more clear sorry your help is really appreciated

Comment: are you able to see the list items?, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`selection` is not being updated here, it should be computed based on the `position`. You probably want to something like this:

```
    ((TextView)v).setText(text);
```

Also, it looks like `songTitle` is a list. You should probably rename that to `songTitles` to begin with. Check that the position is within the bounds of your list. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting an error it just does nothing i have edited the code thank you