# ListView select item

Tags: android, listview, select, onclick

I am trying to select an item in a listview and show the user the item he selected but when I click the list item nothing happens.

`songtitle` is a ListArray....

```
 ArrayList<String>songtitle = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song,songtitle);
 setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This part above is a summary, not actual code. That part works.  It is the method below that doesn't.

```
  protected void onListIemClick(ListView  , View v, int position, long id){
  super.onListItemClick(c, v, position, id);
      Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the color: " + " " + songtitle,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Which item was Selected From a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196552/detecting-which-item-was-selected-from-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method name above is misspelled, which you can verify in your app by adding the @Override annotation.

Are you using custom views?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misspelled the name of the method you are overriding. It should be `onListItemClick(...)`. You should add @Override to methods you intend to override, so that the compiler warns you if the method could not be found in the super class.

Comment: Thannk you guys yall were a big help